# mutt send mail from command line, with headers inside text file

Tags: email, mutt, at

Can mutt send mail from command line without command line parameters, with subject, cc, bcc, reply-to, in-reply-to all defined inside mail.txt file with body of the message too (the same file format like mutt opens to me when i press m-send mail, or r-reply to mail).

... So that I can:

- press 'r' on received mail, prepare my reply message, save it with ':w ~/preparedmail.txt' in vim ... cancel sending
- and than run $ at 8:00 <<< "mutt < ~/preparedmail.txt"

... or is there other tool that will accept this file format. Or other way to achieve this.

Comment: if you can run `at 8:00 am <<< mutt `, what's the problem with using command-line options, e.g. running `at 8:00 am <<< cat ~/preparedmail.txt | mail -s subject recipient@example.com` ?

Comment: @cas it is grate when i want to send new message. But when i want to REPLY there are special headers that i want to invoke, like in-reply-to: hexNumbersLine ...and mutt itself prepare all that well in interactive use with 'r' shortcut, it also prepares 'include original message' and stuff.

Comment: yes. you can write the msg in mutt, and save it to a file.  you can use any mail program (mail, sendmail, a perl script, etc) to send it.

Comment: @cas hm, sorry, so you actually meant 'mail' not 'mutt' inside your first comment. ok i will just find out what is most easy to configure for imap.

Comment: what's imap got to do with it?  you're saving your edited msg to `~/preparedmail.txt`

Comment: @cas mutt is well configured for my mail server. never used mail nor sendmail. ok python could be few-line solution. but i bet that 'mail -s subject ...' do not know my mail server, my credentials, my imap password. so i need to learn their config ways. and hope to find easy one.

Comment: imap has nothing to do with sending mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `sendmail` or `postfix` to deliver the mail, you can use

```
sendmail -t <~/preparedmail.tx
```

and it will extract the destination recipient(s) from any `To:` `Cc:` or `Bcc:` header lines in the file (upto the first blank line) and send the file as mail.

---

For people having configured a tool like `mutt` to send mail directly,
an easy solution is to use **msmtp**, a program to send a prebuilt mail which also takes `-t` like sendmail to get the recipients, and is much easier to configure for smtp with credentials than postfix or sendmail. Here is an example `~/.msmtprc` to send mail to gmail:

```
account gmail
 host smtp.gmail.com
 port 587
 tls on
 # from myname@gmail.com
 auto_from on
 auth on
 user myname@gmail.com
 # password mypassword
 passwordeval gpg -d ~/.msmtp.password.gpg

account default : gmail
```

Don't forget to `chmod og= ~/.msmtprc`.

Comment: nice, but configuring sendmail (which is also mail-server as i understand) for imap, than credentials... seems little complicated

Comment: I agree. you could also look at `msmtp`, a program to send a prebuilt mail which takes `-t` like sendmail, and is much easier to configure for smtp with credentials than postfix or sendmail.

Comment: i am marking your answer as correct, because of now mentioning MSMTP too. For my situation (using external smtps's not own mail-server), msmtp is the BEST tool... maybe you should add that info inside 'for us without sendmail/postfix/exim ambitions', for external smtps like mutt+gmail users.

Answer (score 0):

The `mutt` command supports a `-H` option, with these docs:

```
-H draft
      Specify  a  draft  file which contains header and body to use to
      send a message.
```

You can create one of these draft files "by hand" if you want, but I believe it is the same format that Mutt uses when "postponing" an email (sometimes called a "draft").

In Mutt, you can author an email, then use `P` to postpone it — this will create the file with headers included.
The defalt location it is saved on my system is `~/postponed`, but you can find the path inside Mutt with `:echo $postponed`.

Note: that file will contain multiple emails, if you have multiple postponed.